# Doctrine: Relation One to One (simple)

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

Simple question i have a collection Users and Users_Preferences. Users Preferences are suppose to a be an extension of users. For example:

```
Users
--------------------------------
Id | Name
1  | Test
2  | Luis
3  | Lopes

Users_Preferences
--------------------------------
Id | User_ID | Color | TrackSystem | ReceiveNewsletter
1  |    1    | Green |  after_seen |        no
2  |    3    | Red   | dont_track  |        yes
```

So as you can see i want to create a relation but there may not be records on users_preferences as i am not forcing people to pick their preferences neither set defaults.

ALSO i would like to access it from my Users Repository and Entity.

```
# src/CrazyBundle/Controllers/WhateverController.php
/** @var UsersPreferences $userPreferences **/
$userPreferences = $this->getUser()->getPreferences();
$userPreferences->getColor()

// OR
$this->getUser()->getPreference("color")
```

This should be a basic question for someone who works with Symfony :). The best Practise first please.

Thanks

Comment: use this for the relation [OneToOne-Doctrine](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/reference/association-mapping.html#one-to-one-unidirectional)

Comment: The question still the same. That makes total sense -- I was doing Bidirectonal and thats the reason for the problems when trying to inser. About the 2nd part of the question if i retrieve that protected var will i have the Entity Preferences ? Well make sense that i do. I would be able on TWIG to do something like user.preferences.color ?

Comment: yes, if you have an user object you can get the preferences object and then get the color

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume, that User and UserProperty are entites.

For the User entity you can aet a preference attribute, with a OneToOne relation:

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="UserPreferences")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="preference_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=true)
 **/
protected $preference;
```

You generate a getter and a setter for it.

After this you can get the UserPreference entity from the User:

```
$user->getPreference()->getColor()
```

Or in TWIG:

```
{{ user.preference.color}}
```

Comment: will try this out, was pretty much what i said on my own comment. Its those weird cases u dont find a solution and when u ask for help it just pops over like "wtf u have been there all this time WHY NOW" :)